# AngularJS Circular Dependency Detected But I don't See It

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the following circular dependency error from Angular

`Circular dependency found: Auth <- APIInterceptor <- $http <- $compile`

And Auth signature looks like this

```
.factory('Auth', function($rootScope,APIHelper,$q,$http,$localstorage,$window) {
   /* Implementation Here */
}
```

And the API Interceptor Looks like this

```
.service('APIInterceptor',function($rootScope,$log,Auth){
   /* Implementation Here */
}
```

Where is the immediate circular dependency that it is complaining about?

Any obvious way that I can fix something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Any $http interceptor makes $http to depend on it, so any other service using $http will depend on the interceptor as well.

Comment: @ConstantinePoltyrev is there anyway around this using $injector or something else?

Comment: I am using events to decouple the processing. In my  interceptor I fire an event that gets processed elsewhere.

Comment: That is a good idea, for shortness of time right now, I am removing the $http dependent calls form Auth and putting them in their own service

Comment: By the way, your example code looks like a design flaw. Why would you need to use $http from inside request interceptor?